# Powers in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Ler $R$ be a ring with unity  $1_R$.
If $x \in R $ and $n \in \mathbb{Z} $ how can I compute $(-x)^n $?. Is it equal to $-x^n $ or $x^n $?

Comment: Isn't it a function of $n$, even in common cases like the reals?

Comment: What is your definition of $x^n$?

Answer (score 4):

$(-x)^n = ((-1) \cdot x)^n = (-1)^nx^n$. Whether this is $-x^n$ or $x^n$ will depend whether $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: But we can get that $x^2x\neq xx^2$,

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Conventionally rings are stipulated to be associative, in which case $x^2x = xx^2$.

Comment: But it's not given

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg The OP said "Let $R$ be a ring"; the word "ring" means associative unless the OP says otherwise.

Comment: I mean that $x^2x\neq xx^2$. In the associative ring the needed is obvious of course.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg In an associative ring, $x^2x = (xx)x = x(xx) = xx^2$.

Comment: $x^2 x = (xx)x = x(xx) = xx^2$.  I don't see the confusion.